# ASP.net: Sqldatasource and Session variable

Tags: asp.net

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfDualInitials" runat="server" Visible="false" OnInit="hfDualInitials_OnInit" />
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsStoreNo" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnStr %>"
        SelectCommand="select * from AccountCancellation_Process 
                       where store_num in (select distinct storeno from franchisedata where initials in (@DualInitials))
                       order by CustomerName ASC" >
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="hfDualInitials" DbType="String" Name="DualInitials" />
        </SelectParameters>                     
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I have a Sqldatasource with the above select command and the below code to set the hiddenfield value

```
Protected Sub hfDualInitials_OnInit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)        
    Dim _DualInitials As String = "('P2','7T')"
    Session.Add("DualInitials", _DualInitials)
    Me.hfDualInitials.Value = Session("DualInitials")
End Sub
```

I'm mocking the Session with ('P2','7T') that is going to pass into the above sql command.
when i run the query:

```
select * from AccountCancellation_Process where store_num in (select distinct storeno from franchisedata where initials in ('P2','7T'))
```

it return some data but in my Sqldatasource select command. It return nothing. my guess is because of the where initials in (@DualInitials) the ( ) that is already in the hiddenfield but if i remove the ( ) and just have @DualInitials. I will get "Incorrect syntax near '@DualInitials'."

Does anyone know any workaround or where i get it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Check out answers to the [ADO.NET TableAdapter parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649838/ado-net-tableadapter-parameters) question.

You have a query with a string parameter, not an array parameter. So, when you pass "('P2','7T')" you think that the final query is

```
WHERE initials IN ('P2', '7T')
```

In reality it is

```
WHERE initials IN ('(''P2'', ''7T'')')
```

If it is only going to be two initials then just rewrite using the OR statement. Otherwise I don't know good solution outside of those mentioned in the other thread.

Comment: Any particular reason why I got -1 here? The IN statement treats the parameter as a string and not a sequence. I gave a solution to Jack's problem. wtf?

Answer (score 0):

You can't paramterize an IN statement in SQL like that. You'll have to use string concatenation of the SQL instead (bad) or some other technique like parsing a delimited string.

Answer (score 0):

Without running the sample, I can't be sure, but what about

```
WHERE initials IN (<%=Eval(@DualInitials)%>)
```